# Generate identifiers for a collection of types

Tags: c++, templates

Let's say I have a collection of types `A`, `B`, `C`, ....

Those types are only to be used for tag dispatching, so I want them to be empty / stateless and minimal (empty body) :

```
struct A {};
struct B {};
struct C {};
```

What I then need, is to have a way for a unique ID to be created for each type. This ID also has to be a compile time constant.

My first attempt on this would, very [typically](http://ideone.com/FS9z01), have a structure that specializes over each type, with a `static const` member holding the value of the ID :

```
template <typename T>
struct getID;

template <>
struct getID<A>
{
    static const int ID = 1;
};

template <>
struct getID<B>
{
    static const int ID = 2;
};

template <>
struct getID<C>
{
    static const int ID = 3;
};

template<typename T>
void testID(T val)
{
    cout << getID<T>::ID << endl;
}

int main()
{
    testID(A{});
    testID(B{});
    testID(C{});

    return 0;
}
```

1. Is there a more concise implementation ?
2. I reckon it's a poor design that for every new structure I add to the "collection", a different part of the code must be correctly updated. Is there a way have / generate this struct -> ID mapping ?

Comment: Have you considered using `<typeinfo>` and `typeid` ?

Comment: Why not make some template `template <unsigned int ID> struct MyType {};` -- then the template argument itself could serve as an ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `types<Ts...>` list.  `typedef` a central instance with your types listed in order.  Use index into said list as unique id, which can be bijectively associated with the type at compile time (or, in certain cases, run time).

As an alternative, abuse `__LINE__` and use macros all in one file.

```
template<class...>struct types{typedef types type;};
template<class T, class types>struct index_of_type;
template<class T, class... Ts>
struct index_of_type<T, types<T, Ts...>>:
  std::integral_constant< unsigned, 0 >
{};
template<class T, class T0, class... Ts>
struct index_of_type<T, types<T0, Ts...>>:
  std::integral_constant< unsigned, type_index<T, types<Ts...>>::value+1 >
{};
template<unsigned N, class types>struct type_at_index;
template<unsigned N, class T0, class... Ts>
struct type_at_index<N, types<T0, Ts...>>:type_at_index<N-1, types<Ts...>> {};
template<class T0, class... Ts>
struct type_at_index<0, types<T0, Ts...>> {
  typedef T0 type;
};
template<unsigned N, class types>
using type_at_index_t = typename type_at_index<N,types>::type;
```

Comment: Note that the above can be done with less recursion at a high constant cost if your type list starts breaking into the 100s.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need the IDs to be persistent, you could do this:

```
class A {};
class B {};
class C {};

int getNextID()
{
   static int nextID = 0;
   return ++nextID;
}

template <typename T> struct GetID
{
   static int id()
   {
      static int id = getNextID();
      return id;
   }
};

int main()
{
   cout << GetID<A>::id() << endl;
   cout << GetID<B>::id() << endl;
   cout << GetID<C>::id() << endl;
   cout << GetID<int>::id() << endl;
   cout << GetID<C>::id() << endl;
};
```

Output from running the above program:

```
1
2
3
4
3
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this if I`m right:

```
#define STRINGIFY(x) STRINGIFY2(x)
#define STRINGIFY2(x) #x
#define GET_ID ((int)(STRINGIFY(__FILE__)":"STRINGIFY(__LINE__)))
```

Note that two instances of this macro on the same line in the same file may produce the same number.